# Apps Script - Missing ; before statement

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to create an if else statement to check if certain variables are blank or not. When I run the following script, I receive this error: Missing ; before statement. (line 63, file "Code"). Line 63 is: } else (salary != " " && compBonus == " ") {

```
 if (salary && compBonus != " ") {
   letterSev&CB (copyID, obj); 
  } else if (salary == " " && compBonus != " "){
    letterCB(copyID, obj);
  } else (salary != " " && compBonus == " ") {
    letterSEV(copyID, obj);
  }
```

Comment: `letterSev&CB (copyID, obj);`

Comment: Thanks epascarello. What should I do?

Comment: Did you really intend to use the bitwise `&` ?

Comment: Good point, I removed it from letterSevCB (copyID, obj);, but im still receiving the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The else statement does not have a clause/condition

```
} else (salary != " " && compBonus == " ") {
```

If you need to check it, you need to use `else if`, if you do not need it, than get rid of it.

Comment: Thank you sir. I removed it.